# Can you apply technical analysis indicators to general data?

Tags: data-analysis

I collect data, for example, "how many people mentioned 'Bitcoin' on an investing community", I take the data for daily, so it's like "5/1,231;5/2,156;5/3,223" and so on. So basically not relevant to financial market price actions, but just a type of general data. Here as a newbie to the world of data science, I wonder the indicators which called "technical indicators" can be applied to such general data. For example, I can see sometimes people use "(simple) moving average" to general data, but then "moving average crossover" (e.g. 50sma crossing up 100sma) is effective to them? Or how about RSI(Relative Strength Index)? I can know the uptrend data could go down if I see divergence on the data and its RSI? Other major technical indicators?